# How to keep the actual sf::Sprite object in an array or vector? C++

Tags: c++, scope, sfml

Inside my class(in some_game_object.h), in the private section, I have the following little code snippet

```
sf::Sprite some_sprite;
std::vector<sf::Sprite> sprites;
```

and inside the .cpp file some_game_object.cpp I have the following

```
void some_game_object::set_texture(sf::Texture t) {
    sprites[0].setTexture(t);
}
```

but the texture is never changed. I am unable to change the position of the sprite in another function and actually drawing the sprite with the texture is not possible. The only way to actually access this sf::Sprite object "some_sprite" and change it is by calling it directly, inside the .cpp file. Returning it to my main.cpp file makes that returned object/reference completely useless since it contains old information of a moving object. Referencing it inside the some_game_object.cpp via the sprites vector does NOTHING. Using an array instead (std::array sprites; sprites[0] = some_sprite) is also useless. The data is there. If I look at sprites[0]->getTexture().getSize(); it is the right side. The sprite has the initialized coordinates, but cannot draw the texture nor get the latest coordinates(when not referensing some_sprite directly).

How do I reference and save sprites in some form or vector or array, both is fine, without loosing the ACTUAL object?

Comment: Have a look at how to make a [mcve]. The mistake is not shown in your code example, so it's not possible to answer your question. `some_sprite` and the vector are 2 different objects, so they will never reference the same thing. C++ uses value sematics by default.

Comment: Secret code or not, you’ll still have to create an [mre]. We don’t need your actual code, just something that reproduces the same problem, in as small as possible an example. Side note: we specifically ask the community to help moderate and curate the content on this site, so I people like super will continue to do so wether you tell them not to or not. You may want to take the [tour] to get a better understanding of what Stack Overflow is about and check out our [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct).

Answer (score 0):

You have two main options. You can either create a dynamic object and store a pointer too it (preferably a smart pointer), or you can create an automatic object and move it into the container.

For your purposes it would probably be simpler to store a container of dynamic objects. This means your created object will last as long as your program runs or it is deleted (manually or automatically through RAII). It will also only be accessable by pointers to it and will not get copied (only the pointers will be copied). For example to store a vector of smart pointers to sf::Sprite obejcts:

```cpp
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<sf::Sprite>> sprites;
auto sprite = std::make_shared<sf::Sprite>(); // <-- Make the new object
sprites.emplace_back(sprite); // <-- Copy its pointer into the vector

...
sprites[0]->setTexture(t); // <-- Modifies the same sprite object since it hasnt been copied
```

In this example I used a `std::shared_ptr` because it can be easily copied and I dont want to overcomplicate the example with `std::move` which would be needed for something like `std::unique_ptr`. But if you want to model the container 'owning' the sprite objects then you should use `std::unique_ptr` instead.

Comment: I cannot initialize [code]sprite[/code] as auto since it exists as a private member in a class, therefore I cannot declare a non static member with placeholder 'auto'.

Comment: `auto` is simply a way to make the compiler decide on the type for me, in this case its so I dont have to type out `std::shared_ptr<sf::Sprite>`. Whats the issue here?